# Convenient way of mapping types in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, api, rest

In web api based projects I often use different classes for one entity. Lets say you use class A in your buisness-logic and if you want to return a result you use a class ADto. I am new in using javascript, typescript with node.js based projects. In ASP .net core you often use automapper to transform types. What is the common way you do that in typescript? I did not come to a good result. Writing that boilerplate-code by yourself is not the way to go I think.

Comment: Questions asking to find or recommend a library are off-topic on SO. Come up with [mcve] of what you are trying to achive.

Comment: https://khalilstemmler.com/articles/typescript-domain-driven-design/repository-dto-mapper/ and google for more results like this

Comment: I do not search explicit for a library. If it is the common way, then I'm fine.